# Can websites, through cookies or other usual means, access PDFs opened in browser?

Tags: web-browser, cookies, pdf, file-access

Can websites through the use of cookies or other usual means, see the content in a PDF (saved and opened locally or opened from the web) that is also opened in the browser at the same time, or in the past if it can see the PDF and it’s contents as part of the browser’s history?

Answer (score 1):

No. The same browser feature that prevents scripts on security.stackexchange.com from accessing your bank account or Facebook profile also prevent scripts on any website from accessing content opened in your browser from local files. That feature is called "Same-Origin Policy", and it's quite extensive. A few of the things it blocks:

- If website X asks to see the content of website Y, the response content is not readable by X unless Y explicitly consents.
- If website X asks to send any kind of request that couldn't have been sent with an HTML form (e.g. it wants to set custom headers or use the HTTP DELETE verb) to any other site Y, the browser won't even send the request unless Y consents.
- If website X hosts an iframe or other embedded content for site Y, X can't see the embedded contents of Y (and vice versa).
- If website X opens a popup window to site Y, X can't see the contents of the Y in the popup (and vice versa).
- If website X asks to get a list of stored data (like local/session storage, or cookies, though cookies have weird interactions with origins), it can only get the data for X, not for any other site Y.

This all holds true even when Y (or X, or both!) are local "file:"-originating pages.

---

With that said, you do have to consider the security of how the user *got* and *used* that PDF. For example, if they downloaded it from your website, then you need to make sure that there's no way for an attacker to fake being a different user and download their PDF. If the user is to send the PDF somewhere, an attacker could set up a phishing page or phishing email address or similar to try and get the user to send the PDF to the wrong place. If the PDF name is predictable, the attacker also *might* be able to tell whether it has been opened; there are side-channel attacks in browsers that can sometimes reveal whether a specific URL has been visited before, even though other sites can't see the content at that URL.